# How to change the state of the checkbox using a method?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox

I need to create a method and change the state of the checkbox from checked to unchecked and vice versa by calling a method.

```
onEventListener: (event,props) => {
      if (event.key === " ") {
         console.log ("Check box is "+ !event.target.checked );
           props.onEventListener({onChecked: !event.target.checked});
       }
```

onChecked will be used to change the state , It is a boolean .

```
render (
<div>
 <input
            type="checkBox"
            onKeyDown={props.onEventListener}
            defaultChecked = {props.onChecked}

          />
</div>
)
```

Comment: Why not use setstate?` this.setState({onChecked: !event.target.checked });`

Comment: Please add some context... [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), who passes `props.onEventListener`, why you need to create such method? Maybe there is a better solution

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation of React.

```jsx
class Reservation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isGoing: true,
      numberOfGuests: 2
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <label>
          Is going:
          <input
            name="isGoing"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.isGoing}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Number of guests:
          <input
            name="numberOfGuests"
            type="number"
            value={this.state.numberOfGuests}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        </label>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

This handles state changes both for checkboxes and text inputs.